# Wordpress last class not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a gallery which should display 3 columns, the first two columns have a certain class and work absolutely fine but I am trying to add a "last class" to my third column - for some reason it's not working. Find my code below:

```
        <?php 

        $mod =1;
        if ( $images = get_posts(array(
           'post_parent' => $post->ID,
           'post_type' => 'attachment',
           'numberposts' => -1,
           'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))

        {

         foreach( $images as $image ) {

         $attachmenturl=wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
         $attachmentimage=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, full );
         $imageDescription = apply_filters( 'the_description' , $image->post_content );
         $imageTitle = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $image->post_title );
             if ($mod % 3 == 0) {
            $class = "gallery-entry-img-last";
             }else{
            $class = "gallery-entry-img";
            }
         echo '<div class="'.$class.'"><div class="gallery-entry-img-l"><a rel="next" href="' . $attachmentimage[0] . '"><span class="rollover" ></span><img src="library/tools/timthumb.php?src=' . $attachmentimage[0] . '&amp;w=270&amp;h=198" alt="" /></div></div>';
         }
         $mod++;
        }     
        else {
             echo "No Image";
        }



         ?>
```

Some expert advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it printing the wrong class, or does it print nothing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's printing it in "gallery-entry-img" instead of "gallery-entry-img-last".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

increment your `$mod` variable inside **foreach** loop, like:

```
foreach(.....) {
 ......
 $mod++;
}
```